# Concat classname with variable Angular 2

Tags: angular, angular2-template, classname

I want something like `class = "myClass {{classVar}}"`

I am trying to concat class name with variable value in scope but not working.

```
<div *ngFor="let classVar of classList" >
  <span [ngClass]="'myClass' classVar "></span>                
</div>
```

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Add a `+` and a space:

```
<div *ngFor="let classVar of classList" >
  <span [ngClass]="'myClass ' + classVar"></span>                
</div>
```

Answer (score 11):

You can use it like :

```
[ngClass]="'myClass' + classVar "
```

**OR**

```
ngClass="myClass {{ classVar }}"
```

**OR**

```
[class]="'myClass' + classVar "
```

**OR**

```
class="myClass {{ classVar }}"
```

Comment: Is where any difference between `[ngClass]="'myClass' + classVar "` and `[class]="'myClass' + classVar "`???

Comment: @GilEpshtain seems you can find your answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45321551/2118777