# Linking classes between ts and html replaces instead of appending

Tags: angular, angular-material

I ran into a strange Angular behavior...  I don't know if it ever happened to any of you.

Binding variable applying the traditional binding by using the double curly brace syntax is not going to work as expected, ***it will replace previous classes already associated instead of appending***.

Did you know how to concatenate classes instead of replacing existing ones?

As you can see from this example, here it replaces the classes associated with `mat-raised-button` of material.

***Simple test case :***

**html**

```
<button mat-raised-button class="myClass">BUTTON</button>
<button mat-raised-button class="{{test}}">BUTTON</button>
```

**.ts**

```
export class AppComponent {
   ...
   test = 'myClass';
   ...
}
```

**css**

```
.myClass {
  background: red;
}
```

[Stackblitz test case](https://stackblitz.com/edit/add-angular-material-924v7u)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, try using `ngClass` directive from Angular to append.

https://alligator.io/angular/class-binding-ngclass-angular/

Comment: Fast and easy. Thanks

Comment: I wonder if this will solve your problem, you want to add a variable string as a class to the element, I am thinking....

Comment: If you want to append to a class you already have, you can try out this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49026960/concat-classname-with-variable-angular-2

Answer (score 2):

Use `ngClass` directive to append your classes based on conditions.

```html
<button mat-raised-button ngClass="{{test}}">BUTTON</button>
```

Comment: Fast and easy. Thanks