# How to show two different font awesome icons for two different array values

Tags: javascript, html, angular, font-awesome

I am trying to get the value from Public api, and binding those value in the html but I need to show two different icons for two different values which I am binding using ngFor in the html.

My Array Response

```
ArrayValue
: 
Array(2)
0
: 
{icon: 'fas fa-<insert font awesome icon name>', text: 'Flowers'}
1
: 
{icon: 'fas fa-<insert font awesome icon name>', text: 'Animals'}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="variety">
  <div *ngFor="let show of ArrayValue">{{show.text}}</div>
</div>
```

How can I add two different font awsome icons for show.text(Flowers) and show.text(Animals) in the above ngFor, any answers ?

Comment: Please visit [help], take [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research, search for related topics on SO; if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output, preferably in a [Stacksnippet](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/)

Answer (score 0):

```html
<div class="variety">
  <div *ngFor="let show of ArrayValue">
     <i class="fas" [ngClass]="'fa-' + show.text">
  </div>
</div>
```

---

Alternatively: you can do the following.

> Courtesy: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49027045/2533109

```html
<div class="variety">
  <div *ngFor="let show of ArrayValue">
     <i class="fas" ngClass="fa-{{ show.text}}">
  </div>
</div>
```

or even this way.

```
<i class="fas fa-{{ show.text}}">
```