# Difference between [ngClass]="computeClass()" and class="{{computeClass()}}" in Angular 4

Tags: angular, ng-class

What is the difference when computing class using ngClass and directly computing class using the HTML class attribute in Angular 4.

`[ngClass]="computeClass()"`

and

`class="{{computeClass()}}"`

```
computeClass() {
  if (condition) {
    return 'class-a';
  } else {
    return 'class-b';
  }
}
```

Both returns the same result. How does this impact on the performance?

Edit: My question is different from the question marked as duplicate as it compares [ngClass] and [class] whereas, the above comparison is between [ngClass] and class.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Angular \[ngClass\] vs \[class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45321526/angular-ngclass-vs-class)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion Amit. I had set my change detection to ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush

Comment: That is just another change detection that you perform manually after angular has initiated the change detection. That might not solve the problem.

Comment: @MuhammetCanTONBUL i don't think it's the same question tho...similar but is not the same

Answer (score 0):

You are talking about `Interpolation` and `Property Binding`.

Both will give you same result.

**Interpolation**

Interpolation is a special syntax that Angular converts into property binding. It’s a convenient alternative to property binding.

For Ex :

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'my-app',
    template: `<div>
                    <h1>{{citedExample}}</h1>
                    <img src=' https://angular.io/{{imagePath}}'/>
                </div>`
})
export class AppComponent {
    citedExample: string = 'Interpolation';
    imagePath: string = 'assets/images/logos/angular/logo-nav@2x.png';
}
```

**Property Binding**

Property Binding to set an element property to a non-string data value, you must use property binding.

For Ex :

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'my-app',
    template: `<div>
    <button [disabled]='isDisabled'>Try Me</button>
                     </div>`
})
export class AppComponent {
isDisabled: boolean = true;
}
```

**If we decide to use interpolation instead of property binding, the button will always be disabled irrespective of isDisabled class property value is true of false.**

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the documentation of `ngClass` [here.](https://angular.io/api/common/NgClass)

From angular docs:

> The CSS classes are updated as follows, depending on the type of the
>   expression evaluation:
>
> ```
> string - the CSS classes listed in the string (space delimited) are added,
> Array - the CSS classes declared as Array elements are added,
> Object - keys are CSS classes that get added when the expression given in the value evaluates to a truthy value, otherwise they are
> ```
>
> removed.

As you can see `ngClass` takes different types of arguments. If you just pass a string, this css class will be attached to the HTML element. The same way when you use interpolation (as mentioned by Shashikant Devani).

However `ngClass` can do much more. If you pass an object in example you can add multiple css classes conditionally.

It works like this if we apply this to your example:

```
computeClass() {
  return {
     "class-a": condition,
     "class-b": !condition
  };
}
```

This is a normal javascript object. `classA` will only be added if `conditionA` is true and the same applies to `classB`. If you want to learn more about the possibilities of `ngClass` take a look at the documentation.

Answer (score 0):

This `class="{{computeClass()}}"` or `[class]="computeClass()"` is a property binding it just accept string value as name of class or list of classes like this below

```
class="class1 class2"
```

and the you do something like this

```
[class]="condition ? 'class-a' : 'class-b'"
```

as far both why will retern **string value**

**NgClass** is an build in angular directive based on the input will set the class attribute can accept this list of values

- string - the CSS classes listed in the string (space delimited) are added.
- Array - the CSS classes declared as Array elements are added,
- Object - keys are CSS classes that get added when the expression
  given in the value evaluates to a truthy value, otherwise they are
  removed.

an example of *ngClass*

```
[ngClass]="condition ? 'class-a' : 'class-b'"
[ngClass]="{'class-a' :condition ,'class-b':!condition"}
```

is your case both are acceptable but some advanced cases you will find **ngClass** is more probate to use and consider a best practices to handle add or remove class