# How to dynamically add class on click and remove it 2 seconds later?

Tags: html, angular, typescript

I didn't know how to properly formulate my question so I'll try to explain myself here :

In my Angular 7 app, I have a navbar with icons as menu items.

On click, I want them to get a certain class, and the class has to disapear 2 seconds later.

I have 7 elements, here's 2 as an example :

```
        <li class="fushia-icon">
            <a routerLink="/savoir" routerLinkActive="fushia-icon-active" class="animated"
               [class.flip]="this.iconIsClicked" (click)="iconClicked(this.iconIsClicked = true)">
            </a>
        </li>


        <li class="beige-icon">
            <a routerLink="/diplomes" routerLinkActive="beige-icon-active" class="animated"
               [class.flip]="this.iconIsClicked" (click)="iconClicked(this.iconIsClicked = true)">  
            </a>
        </li>
```

In my ts file I did this :

```
 iconClicked(icon){
        setTimeout(()=> {
            icon = false
        }, 2000)
    }
```

But that doesnt do what I want at all since they both get the class, and the iconIsClicked value doesnt return to the element to be analysed (obvious).

I know I could create 7 functions with 7 variables so that each icon has its own stuff, but I'm looking for a quicker way without duplicating code.

Thank

Comment: Are your `li`s in a loop or are static?

Comment: I think the best for you is to use a directive where you implement what you wish !  I'll try

Comment: @xyz no they are static

Comment: @naspy971 A directive is a nice idea as suggested..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So the goal is to use the same method for each menu. The simple choice here is to use a Directive that can easily do what we want to achieve.

I think you can remember things like this: a directive allow you to control the view

I managed to do this easily by using an HostListener with an onClick event on each `li`

You have the stackblitz [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular4-uhcm5p)

---

***extract of:*** **class-changer.directive.ts**

```
constructor(private _ren: Renderer2, private _el: ElementRef) { }

@HostListener('click') onClick() {
    this._ren.addClass(this._el.nativeElement, 'bg-red');
    setTimeout(() => {
      this._ren.removeClass(this._el.nativeElement, 'bg-red');
    }, 2000)
  }
```

---

**EDIT** 
I update my stackblitz. Like this, you can add and remove class easily !

Answer (score 4):

**You can use a [template reference variable](https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax#ref-vars) and add/remove ([Element.classList](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList) methods) .**

*HTML*

```
<li class="fushia-icon">
    <a #fushiaIcon class="animated" (click)="iconClicked(fushiaIcon)"></a>
</li>
<li class="beige-icon">
    <a #beigeIcon class="animated" (click)="iconClicked(beigeIcon)"></a>
</li>
```

*TS*

```
iconClicked(menuIcon: HTMLElement) {
    menuIcon.classList.add('flip');

    setTimeout(()=> {
        menuIcon.classList.remove('flip');
    }, 2000)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There are more than one issues in your code.

1- You need to use `[ngClass]` instead of `[class]`.

2- You shouldn't use `this` in template files. `this.iconIsClicked` is not a valid value.

3- What are you trying to accomplish by calling `iconClicked(this.iconIsClicked = true)`? It does not make sense as you pass a primitive (**meaning you are not passing by reference**). Therefore modifications in the `iconClicked()` method does not affect template as its scope is ended when function returns.

If you try to add css class `.flip` to the clicked `li`, there are several thing you can do. Maybe you can do like the following. Since your `li` items are static, you need to give each one of them a template reference such as `#diplomesLiRef` and pass it to the component's method.

**Template file**

```
<li class="beige-icon">
    <a routerLink="/diplomes" 
        routerLinkActive="beige-icon-active"
        #diplomesLiRef
        class="animated"
        (click)="toggleClass(diplomesLiRef, 'flip')">  
    </a>
</li>
```

**Component File**

```
toggleClass = (liRef, cssClass) => {
    liRef.classList.add(cssClass);
    setTimeout(() => {liRef.classList.remove(cssClass)},2000);
}
```

But, as the commenters on your question stated, the best way to accomplish what you need is to create a `directive`.

Comment: He can totally use [class.flip], it's allowed ! see here: https://toddmotto.com/ng-class-angular-classes#property-binding-with-class

Comment: @BenThie You are right. The usage is valid: [https://stackoverflow.com/a/45321551/1331040](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45321551/1331040). Thanks for clarification.

Comment: @HarunYılmaz No problem ;)