# Angular HTML class.otherclass explanation

Tags: css, angular

I have seen this HTML line in an Angular project:

```
<div id="player" class="player" [class.voted]="booleanvar">
```

The CSS contains a defintion of `.player.voted`

I'm not really sure what this part means: `[class.voted]="booleanvar"`

Comment: It adds or removes the "voted" class based on the value of `booleanvar`. It's a bit easier (?) to read than `[ngClass]="{player: true, voted: booleanvar}"`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Difference between \[ngClass\] vs \[class\] binding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45321526/difference-between-ngclass-vs-class-binding)

Comment: @HereticMonkey please add your comment as an answer and I'll accept it

Comment: It's the same as the answer in the duplicate.

Comment: It is angular class binding. You can find the documentation here [link](https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax#class-binding)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**I hope you help it**

`[class.voted]="booleanvar"` this means the element add a class "`voted`" when "`booleanvar`" poperty or a variable value is true.

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  template:`
    <div id="player" class="player" [class.voted]="booleanvar">
  `
})
export class AppComponent {
  booleanvar:boolean = true;
}
```

when `booleanvar = false` then the render element like '`<div id="player" class="player">'`

**Otherwise it's render `<div id="player" class="player voted">`**

Answer (score 1):

This is one way of dynamically applying a class to an HTML element in Angular.

If `booleanvar` equates to `true` then the css class `voted` will be applied, so long as its defined correctly in CSS file. If it equates to `false`, then the class will not be applied.

```
<div id="player" class="player" [class.voted]="booleanvar">
```