# What is the difference between [ngClass]/[class] and [className] in Angular 9?

Tags: angular

There are a lot of SO questions about the difference between ngClass and class like this one:

[Difference between [ngClass] vs [class] binding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45321526/difference-between-ngclass-vs-class-binding)

But you can also use `[className]` as a binding. What is the difference between `[ngClass]` and `[className]` and when should you use one over the other?

Comment: Does binding to className *do anything*, in general (i.e. where not specifically provided for by a component)? I've always used class.

Comment: @jonrsharpe yes it behaves exactly the same way as binding to ngClass would. Therefore i would really like to know what exactly the difference would be.

Comment: Ah - [*"there is an automatic attribute-to-property mapping in Angular for several common attributes. These include class/className..."*](https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax#binding-targets) - given that's the only reference to it, I'd stick with what's [documented](https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax#class-binding). If it behaves the same way, what makes you think there's a difference?

Comment: @jonrsharpe so what does that mean? That `className` is nothing more then a synonym for `ngClass` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like `[className]`, `[ngClass]` allows to bind a string expression of space separated class names:

```
<some-element [ngClass]="'first second'">...</some-element>
<some-element [className]="'first second'">...</some-element>
```

But `[ngClass]` also allows to bind the class names as an array or as an object (where each property key is a class name which is applied or not according to the associated value):

```
<some-element [ngClass]="['first', 'second']">...</some-element>
<some-element [ngClass]="{'first': condition1, 'second': condition2}">...</some-element>
```

These syntaxes, which can be convenient, are not supported by `[className]` since [className](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/className) is a string property of HTML elements.

See [this stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-anzvqz?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html) for a demo.

Comment: This is only true for ViewEngine. With Angular Ivy, both approach is identical https://stackblitz.com/edit/ngclass-class-ivy?file=src/app/app.component.html

Answer (score 0):

As @chau-tran said, they are almost identical, but. Even in Ivy I've found the case where [ngClass] is more powerful than a regular [class] binding.

You can't bind multiple classes with [class] binding like this:

`<div [class]="{'class1 class2': true}"></div>`

In this case, you'll get this error:

`Error: Failed to execute 'add' on 'DOMTokenList': The token provided ('class1 class2') contains HTML space characters, which are not valid in tokens.`

But it's totally valid with [ngClass]:

`<div [ngClass]="{'class1 class2': true}"></div>`

https://stackblitz.com/edit/ngclass-class-ivy-qcg3ta?file=src/app/app.component.html